# Facebook Like button flips backs to 'unliked' state after clicking

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I have added a Facebook Like button on my [Tumblr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumblr) blog (in the template): both the iFrame code and the [Open Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Open_Graph_protocol) tags. The button shows up normally below each blog article. When I click the button, it changes its status to 'liked', but flips back to the original state after one second.

The HTML source of the blog article is (iframe part):

```html
<iframe class="fb_button" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=APP_ID&href=http://www.beyondbrands.nl/post/7354959316/startup-weekend-amsterdam-join-crowdriding&send=false&layout=button_count&width=90&show_faces=true&action=like&colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

OG tags:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Beyond Brands Blog, StartUp Weekend Amsterdam about to get started" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.beyondbrands.nl/post/7354959316/startup-weekend-amsterdam-join-crowdriding" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://26.media.tumblr.com/avatar_6e2d27950ebb_128.png" /> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Beyond Brands Blog" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="598414663" />
```

Comment: Having the exact same problem and I'm getting nowhere with Facebook's documentation or forums, so I bountied this question.

Comment: I had the same problem, in the end I discovered it was just me, no other people experienced this issue. I think it may be a problem of cookies, or facebook remembering you and causing conflicts. Anyway after some days it went back ok. BTW facebook documentations SUCKS.

Comment: @Jose Faeti I tested his page that he links to and it was doing the same thing for me too.

Answer (score 11):

I'm a Partner Engineer at Facebook. We've been tracking this issue internally and we pushed out a fix in the last 24 hours to fix this. You could manually fix the issue by running the urls through the linter, but obviously this wasn't a scalable solution. If you see this issue still happening, let me know so we can reproduce and diagnose any lingering issues.
This was the bug id we used to track it (as posted by other users):
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18591

Comment: @JefF: You don't need to tell us that you're from Facebook all the time. Everyone know it from your profile :) .. Welcome!

Answer (score 4):

You need to [URL encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the URL that you want to like into `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.beyondbrands.nl%2Fpost%2F7354959316%2Fstartup-weekend-amsterdam-join-crowdriding`

So it would be something like this instead:

```
<iframe class="fb_button" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=141659102581634&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.beyondbrands.nl%2Fpost%2F7354959316%2Fstartup-weekend-amsterdam-join-crowdriding&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=90&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have now URL encoded the page URL by using {URLEncodedPermalink} in Tumblr. The Like button now 'sometimes' works. I've checked the HTML with looks fine in all the cases. However, it now sometimes flips back, somethings it works fine.

Comment: I went in and liked your last 10 posts and they all worked on Chrome/Win7. What browser are you still experienceing it with? If it happens again, the putting the url into the Facebook linted tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Answer (score 2):

This issue is coming on Facebook, particularly on newly registered domain names. It has nothing to do with the code.

How old is your domain?

Also, try the [Facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/).

Does it fetch your meta tags correctly?

**Update:**

This has been resolved!

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18591

Comment: Seems to work now. Does the Facebook spider, that takes up to 24 hours to visit the site has an impact?

Comment: send me url to ur page... you can investigate the response which facebook sends via NET panel of firebug. And its not about facebook's spider, rather facebook has a list of blocked domains {which is magically decided}

Comment: this has been resolved :) http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18591

Answer (score 0):

Try this iframe:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.beyondbrands.nl%2Fpost%2F7354959316%2Fstartup-weekend-amsterdam-join-crowdriding" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height: 62px; width: 100%" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

It was taken from [lint](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.beyondbrands.nl%2Fpost%2F7354959316%2Fstartup-weekend-amsterdam-join-crowdriding).

Comment: Thanks for this, but then I will loose the Facebook Insights data. It seems to work now, Facebook has recognized it is a bug on their end.